# chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener not working before the page loads

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, say, when the user clicks the extension button if the websites are within the list of "known websites", they will be redirected to the corresponding pages I have made for this website.

My idea is that:

1. In Background.js
   I have chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener, which chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { "message": "clicked_browser_action" }) like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { "message": "clicked_browser_action" })
})
```

2. In Content.js
   There is a chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener, it does something like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request) {
        if (request.message === "clicked_browser_action") {
            const domain = window.location.hostname
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "go_to_info_page", "url": domain})
        }
    }
)
```

3. And then back to background.js, it receives the Message sent from content.js, and updates the URL for the tab (or create a new tab).

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request) {
        if (request.message === "go_to_info_page") {
            chrome.tabs.update({"url": request.url})
            return true;
        }
    }
)
```

It works perfectly but for the case that a page loads very slowly, and the user clicks the button right away, it doesn't work. I suspect it's onMessage.addListener not working until some point that the page loads. But spent hours, I still don't know how to solve it. Any help would be really really appreciated!!

I have thought of a workaround that get URL in background.js so no sendMessage is needed. Is it a good approach?

Comment: You can just do this from the background script: `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => { const domain = new URL(tabs[0].url).hostname })`